# Matching words using regex

Tags: regex

I'm very new on learning regex. I've been trying to understand how can I control quantifiers to match a single word out of a string. I know there are vast resources out there but it's hard to find any specific term I'm after.

What I would like to know is how to match the word `He` from the below string? It would be better if I could know how to match `it` as well (i meant, matching any positional word):

```
He found it difficult.

[a-zA-Z].*?    --it's a silly try to match "He"
```

Comment: Split with `\s+` or `\W+` and get the "words" by indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will find 2 letter word surrounded by space or if the sentence start with a 2 letter word, in this case "He", it will also be found. Thus "He" and "it" will both be found.

```
(( .. )|(^.. ))
```

**EDIT - MORE IN DEPTH EXPLANATION**

to search for 2 letter words, we use . (dot) for each of the 2 characters, so thus we have ".." but this will find any 2 characters, so we need to surround the with spaces so we search for " .. " and thus only if 2 characters are surrounded by spaces, will this be found. but now we have a new problem. the first 2 letter word in the sentence does not have a space infront of it. so it will nou be found. thus we add the | (or) to the exrpression to search for the same expression, except this time we exchange the starting space with ^ to indicate if the sentence start with a 2 letter word followed by a space, it should also find that word. so in short we find " .. " - 2 letter word surounded by space and we also find "^.. " to letter word at start of sentence followed by a space.

**EDIT - BETTER REGEX**

a better regex would be `(( [a-z][a-z] )|(^[a-z][a-z] ))` since this will only search for words, as apposed to " 12 " that would also result in a match. this regex however assumes that you search while ignoring case, otherwise it will not work correctly.

Comment: No way!!  This is what i was looking for. Is it possible to make a oneliner explanation as to how you did that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @shayan i added a better alternative to the answer.